# Entity Framework 4 Code-First many to many insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, many-to-many, code-first

I'm using code-first pattern for database layer.

I have two POCO classes:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    // other fields
}
```

and

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    // other fields
}
```

Then I have data context class:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

And I have an "repository" class:

```
public class OrderRepository
{
    private DataContext dataContext = new DataContext();
    public void Save(Order entity)
    {
        entity.OrderDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        dataContext.Orders.Add(entity);
        dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

When I call this OrderRepository.Save method I get an error: **An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.**

In database I have a table Items, Orders and Items_Orders...I google-d a lot for this error and for EF many-to-many save, but I haven't find anything useful which would help me, because I couldn't find a sample for Code-First principle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably have other entities (from other repositories?) which came from other `DataContext`s related to your `Order` entity. That would cause the error you're seeing.

All repositories should share the same `DataContext` during a unit of work. You typically do this with constructor injection, like this:

```
public class OrderRepository
{
    private readonly DataContext dataContext;
    public void Save(Order entity)
    {
        entity.OrderDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        dataContext.Orders.Add(entity);
        dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public OrderRepository(DataContext dataContext)
    {
        this.dataContext = dataContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How could I create a constructor injection for DataContext class?

Comment: See updated answer. Then use a single `DataContext` for all repositories in a UOW.

Comment: Thank you, that's it! :) Can you recommend me an Entity Framework 4 book/site/blog with fundamental things that everyone who uses it should know?

Comment: I'm the wrong person to ask. I've never read any EF books. But Mark Seeman's *Dependency Injection in .NET* covers EF and MVC integration well.