# The specified type member 'Locale_Section' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.

Tags: c#, webforms, entity-framework-5, asp.net-4.5

I have ran accross a few similare issues to my here on stackoverflow but they did not look to be going deep in to joined tables and I was not able to see anything that applied to my code so I am hoping someone can look over my code bits and tell me why I am getting the

> The specified type member 'Locale_Section' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

```
        private object SetNavItems(string Category, byte CultureID)
    {
        using (var db = new Compleate())
        {
            return (from n in db.Navigation
                    where n.Category == Category && n.Section.Locale_Section.CultureID == CultureID
                    orderby n.Position
                    select new
                    {
                        n.Section.Locale_Section.Title,
                        n.Section.LinkAddress
                    }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Navigation.cs

```
    [Table("Navigation")]
public class Navigation
{
    [Key, Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int NavigationID { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(16), Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Int16 SectionID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SectionID")]
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte Position { get; set; }
}
```

Ssection.cs

```
    [Table("Section")]
public class Section
{
    [Key, Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int16 SectionID { get; set; }

    public Int64 LogoFileID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LogoFileID")]
    public virtual File File { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(15), Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string RouteName { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(15), Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string LinkAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return Type + "/" + RouteName;
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public virtual Locale_Section Locale_Section { get; set; }
}
```

Locale_Section.cs

```
    [Table("Locale_Section")]
public class Locale_Section
{
    [Key, Required, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Int16 SectionID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SectionID")]
    public virtual Section Section { get; set; }

    [Key, Required, Column(Order = 1)]
    public byte CultureID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CultureID")]
    public virtual Culture Culture { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(250)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Synopsis { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have marked `Section_Locale` property in `Section` entity as `NotMapped`. It means that the property is unknown to your mapping and cannot be translated to SQL in Linq-to-Entities query. You cannot use that property without either mapping it or loading all `Navigation` instances to your application by calling for example `ToList` or `AsEnumerable` first (which is most probably pretty bad solution).

Comment: If I remove the `NotMapped` propertie then a column will be made in the DB and would need a value. Is there something I can do to prevent that? The Section Table does not need a column for Local_Section since Local_Section already has a mapping back to Section (on SectionID). The relationship between Section -> Local_Section is One -> Many.

Comment: If you don't map it, you cannot use it in Linq-to-entities query. And if the relation is one-to-many the `Section` class should use contain collection of Local_section. Not only single reference.

Comment: Can you please elaberate on "contain collection of Local_Section". I am very bnew to EFand LINQ.

Comment: Looking around today on break I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735981/how-do-you-actually-perform-relationships-in-entity-framework-4-code-first-ctp-5 which I think is what I need to make the one-many relstion. I will try it when I get home tonight. If I am on the wrong track please correct me.

Comment: When I change it to public virtual List<Locale_Section> Locale_Section { get; set; } then I can no longer access anythingi n hte Locale_Section table. Please help what am I doing wrong?